# Python Pandas Throwing error when calculating mean on timedelta Series

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

in Python Pandas, when trying to calculate the mean of a Series object composed by timedelta objects, it throws the following error:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.pyc in _ensure_numeric(x)
462             x = float(x)
463         except Exception:
--> 464             raise TypeError('Could not convert %s to numeric' % str(x))
465
466     return x

TypeError: Could not convert 658 days, 6:26:00 to numeric
```

It seems not to be able to convert a timedelta (in this case the sum of all values in the Series) to a numeric value in order to calculate the average. Is this a limitation of Pandas ? I am not an expert, but I think it is a very common necessity in statistics. or maybe I am doing something wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version pandas; you need 0.13.0 IIRC at least; numpy >= 1.7.1

Comment: you are right, my current is 0.10.1. I will update it. thank you so much.